# How to assign a JQuery event handlers to a specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Javascript function called Howto that is executed when a button is pressed:

```
function howto(){

   $('#elementtoupdate').ajaxSend(function() {
       //Code to execute
   });

   $('#elementtoupdate').ajaxComplete(function() {
       //Code to execute
   });

   $('#elementtoupdate').load('serverside/file_path.php')
}
```

Using JQuery the function assigns two JQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers, they are initiated when the any AJAX calls are initiated. Then the function continue and calls a JQuery `.load` function, and any code inside the Global Ajax Event Handlers is initiated.

However, as the name the word Global suggests they are also initiated by other Jquery AJAX calls. This unfortunately is undesirable as I have other AJAX calls in the script. I need the code to be executed only when `$('#elementtoupdate').load('serverside/file_path.php')` is executed.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Ok. Comment retracted...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has callbacks on its own that are not global:

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
```

Thus:

```
$('#elementtoupdate').load('serverside/file_path.php', function() {
  // complete
});
```

Comment: Not for `ajaxSend`, though. To support it, the questioner will have to call `$.ajax()` directly and use the `beforeSend` option.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: True that. For OP's use it might be enough to run the `ajaxSend` code inside the `howto` function, though, as they will at least be temporally correlated.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept David Hedlund's answer. For the sake of completeness :

you can change :

```
function howto(){

   $('#elementtoupdate').ajaxSend(function() {
       //code to be executed before send
   });

   $('#elementtoupdate').ajaxComplete(function() {
       //code to be executed after completed
   });

   $('#elementtoupdate').load('serverside/file_path.php')
}
```

to :

```
function howto(){
    //code to be executed before send

    $('#elementtoupdate').load('serverside/file_path.php', function(){
        //code to be executed after completed
    })
}
```